# miktex-makemf did not succeed

Tags: errors

I have these problems:

Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\giuli\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.log

Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\giuli\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makepk.log

Comment: Welcome! Could you please provide a minimal example which reproduces your error? Please also explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: just trying to compile a file given my teacher (to all my class mates it works)

Comment: You can check your `.log` files to find what possibly caused the error. Without knowing your input files nor error log it is hard to guess.